# Delayed job: Set max run time of job , not the worker

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have below piece of code :

```
Converter.delay.convert("some params")
```

Now I want this job to be run for max 1 minute. If exceeded,delayed job should raise the exception.

I tried setting up

```
Delayed::Worker.max_run_time = 1.minute
```

but it seems it sets a timeout on the worker , not on the job.

Converter class is defined in RAILS_ROOT/lib/my_converter.rb

Answer (score 0):

Timeout in the job itself

```
require 'timeout'

class Converter
  def self.convert(params)
    Timeout.timeout(60) do
      # your processing
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this..But I was wondering if delayed job can help in this

Comment: @vipulKumar: there's a caveat: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31757044/125816

Answer (score 0):

```
Delayed::Worker.max_run_time=1.minute
```

Its the max time on each task given to worker. The execution of any task takes more than specified we get exception raised as .

```
 execution expired (Delayed::Worker.max_run_time is only 1 minutes)
```

The worker continue to run and process next tasks.